# Migrate from Testcafe to playwright

Tags: testcafe, playwright-test

We are using Testcafe for a while and we have test automation there in javascript and typescript. We are thinking to move to Playwright is there a way that we can easily migrate without of rewriting all test cases ?

Just wanted to know if anyone can give us some guide?